# How to set a JFrame location beside another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, location

**In Java, how could I set a JFrame to automatically go beside another JFrame?**

So, say I have two `JFrame` objects, `frameA` and `frameB`, and when the program runs, it sets `frameA`s location to be in the middle of the screen by using:

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Now what I want is to make `frameB` to be on the right side of `frameA`, so they would be right beside each other. (`frameA`s right side would be touching `frameB`s left side)

How would you do this?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: *"How would you do this?"*  Put the content of frame A in the `BorderLayout.LINE_START` and the content of frame B in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of a frame 'C' which would be the single frame of the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a test class I created to demonstrate an example of how it could be done. You use the f1.getX() + f1.getWidth() to find to correct location for the second frame.

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
        f1. setSize(100, 100);
        f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f1.setVisible(true);

        JFrame f2 = new JFrame();
        f2.setSize(100, 100);
        f2.setLocation(f1.getX() + f1.getWidth(), f1.getY());
        f2.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
final Rectangle bounds = frameA.getBounds();
frameB.setLocation(bounds.x + bounds.width, bounds.y);
```