# How to create JFrame one next to other?

Tags: java

I have problem. I need to create loop, which creates JFrames next to previous one. Frames have to fill whole screen. 
To determine size of frames I used Toolkit.getScreen() method, but i'm wondering how to determine localization of next frames. 
Is there any method i could use or i have to do it mathematical?

Comment: Ok, i'have done some mathematics and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use the [setLocationRelativeTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component)) method. You can pass the previous JFrame instance as the arguement to this method.

Comment: please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039600/how-to-set-a-jframe-location-beside-another-jframe) answer. It has just a line of mathematics. I guess this will be good to use.